# how to update data from relation many to many table using codeigiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My controller**

```
public function edit($id=''){

        $data['post'] = $this->posts->getpostbyid('posts',$id);
        $data['c'] = $this->posts->categories_post($id);
}

public function update()
    {
      $id = $this->input->post('id');
      $categories = $this->input->post('category');
      foreach ($categories as $category) {

            $data = array(
                'idcategory' => $category
            );
            $this->posts->updatepost('categories_detail', $data,$id);

        }
```

**My model**

```
public function updatepost($table,$data,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('idpost', $id);
        return $this->db->update($table, $data);
    }
public function categories_post($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('categories.idcategory, categories.category_name');
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->join('categories_detail', 'categories_detail.idcategory = categories.idcategory', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('posts', 'posts.idpost = categories_detail.idpost', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('posts.idpost', $id);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
```

**My View**

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post['idpost'] ?>" name="id">
<?php
    foreach ($categories as $data) { ?>
       <div class="form-group">
          <input <?php foreach ($c as $cc) { echo $data->idcategory == $cc['idcategory'] ? 'checked' : ''; } ?> type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="<?php echo $data->idcategory ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $data->category_name ?>
       </div>
<?php } ?>
```

In my case, I have a relation many to many db;

1. posts : idpost, post.
2. categories : idcategory, category_name
3. categories_detail : id, idpost. idcategory

The problem is when I update the categories, it's just insert 1 category eventhought i check 2 or more categories.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are you setting the name attribute for `id`?  You're updating `where idpost = id` but I don't see it being posted anywhere, so `$this->input->post('id') would be `null`

Comment: Additionally it looks like you will only ever update the `categories_detail` table on the same `id`

Comment: in view -> editpost. i set it in type="hidden"

Comment: I just updated my code on view

Comment: You are only posting one `id`, so you are repeatedly updating the same `id`

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: the problem is in category

Answer (score 0):

You are updating `category_details` table with post `id` which will affect all the category. For many to many relation no need `id` in `categories_detail` table.

If you want easy way to update post categories in `categories_detail` table. Just delete all the data of the specific post using `idpost` form `categories_detail` table and insert the new `idpost` and `idcategory`.

As it's many to many relation update a column in many to many table (in this case `categories_detail` table) is very complex and is not suitable.